# Changing complex eigenvalues to real eigenvalues given a $2 \times 2$ matrix and a characteristic equation

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the following: $A = \left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 &-1\cr
5 &4
\end{array}\right].$

I get $\lambda = 2 \pm 2i$; however, I can only input real eigenvalues into the online homework system I am using. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, if it makes you feel any better, I get the same answer as you.

Comment: give us your name, instructor, and address where homework is sent, we will put in the correct answer for you

Comment: $Det(A - \lambda I) = 0 \implies (-\lambda)(4-\lambda)+5 = \lambda^2 - 4\lambda + 5 \implies \lambda = 2 \pm 2i$ by the quadratic formula.